# table row is not fitting in the print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is the html document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M18xM.png).

[This is the print preview of the html table when the javascript print function called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSunW.png)

here is the css code.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    /* page-break-before: always; */
}
table,th,td {
    border: 1px solid #858585;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    background-color: #e78c37;
    color: white;
}

thead {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

i have tried to change the page break property but it doesn't work

Comment: I can't see how, by default, a table would be merged in to that format when printing. Do you have an existing `media=print` stylesheet which is messing up the layout?